# How do I make the alpha channels of my animated sprite see through?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to learn the capabilities of ThreeJS by making a small game. I have an animated sprite that is working great in my scene by using a PlaneGeometry and using a png texture in my MeshBasicMaterial but unfortunately even though my png has an alpha channel, the mesh is displaying the alpha channel as black when instead I'd prefer it to obviously be transparent. Is there a way to correct this?

```
//this is a customer function you can see at the top of my codepen
texture = new THREE.SpriteSheetTexture('assets/monster.png', 4, 1, 250, 4);

//loading the basic material here
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
   map: texture
});
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1);
monster = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( monster );
```

You can view how I have the code laid out here, note though, I cannot get the png resource working on codepen:
https://codepen.io/GreedFeed/pen/yrqpQY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to set the `.transparent` property of the [`THRRE.Material`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material) which states the material transparent and activates the special treatment of transparent objects:

```js
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
   map: texture,
   transparent: true
});
```

[image]

Comment: I am a fool, this is absolutely the solution. I really appreciate you taking the time out of your day to show that off. I appreciate it.

Comment: @GreedFeed You're welcome. It didn't take that much time. Some do crossword puzzles or Sudoku, I answer stackoverflow questions.